# TextWriter references not behaving as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, output-buffering

Ok, I'm cruising through with ILSpy and trying to sort out what's going on here, but I'm not having much luck.

In a given view in ASP.NET MVC4 application (*though, surely this is applicable to MVC3, possibly 2*) that uses the Razor engine, the [`OutputStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.outputstack%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) property inherited from [`WebPageBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is simply a stack of [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) objects.

By pushing and popping from this stack, one can manipulate the output of a given Razor view. I was hoping to leverage this with HTML helper extension methods, however I also noticed that [`ViewContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which is also a public member of [`HtmlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) has **it's own TextWriter**.

Now, I ran a quick check: (*from within a view*)

```
@object.ReferenceEquals(this.ViewContext.Writer, this.OutputStack.Peek()) // True
```

However, the following confuses me to all hell:

```
@{
    // push one on
    OutputStack.Push(new StringWriter());
}
Hello!
@{
    // capture everything and pop it
    string buffer1 = OutputStack.Peek().ToString();
    OutputStack.Pop();
}
<pre>@(buffer1)</pre>

@{
    // apparently it references the top of the OutputStack
    // so this should be essentially the same
    var oldWriter = ViewContext.Writer;
    ViewContext.Writer = new StringWriter();
}
World!
@{
    // revert it and hope for the best
    string buffer2 = ViewContext.Writer.ToString();
    ViewContext.Writer = oldWriter;
}
<pre>@(buffer2)</pre>
```

The results from the above are as follows:

- `Hello!` is captured into `buffer1`, and actually dumped after as `<pre>Hello!</pre>`. This is both expected and desired.
- `World!` on the other hand, is output immediately, followed by an empty `<pre></pre>` block; in other words, it's not capturing anything.

My question is as follows: How do these `TextWriter` objects relate to one another, and why can I not manage the reference through `ViewContext` the same as I can from the top of the  `OutputStack`? (*rather, **how** can I manage the reference through `ViewContext`?*)

---

**Addendum**
<sup>*Details and other crap as I come across it.*</sup>

- The `Writer` property of `ViewContext` doesn't discard values passed to the setter, so it's not just dropping it in the case of the second example.
- Moving along the call stack, `OutputStack` is actually coming from [`PageContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagecontext%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).
- `ViewContext.Writer` is set in `WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()` using the `WebViewPage` property `Output`, *which is the top of the `OutputStack`*! (*is it just me, or is this beginning to look like a rat's nest of dependencies?*)

Comment: What **does** the setter of the `Writer` property of `ViewContext` do? And what does the getter do?

Comment: @CharlieKilian ILSpy shows them as auto-properties... wait; then how am I getting `ReferenceEquals` returning `true`?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Or is this just some research question about the design of Razor views? I am just curious because if you were trying to solve some real world problem and told that to us, maybe there's an easier solution to it.

Comment: This pretty much shows that `ViewContext.Writer` isn't actually being used by Razor to write the output, doesn't it? That is my guess at the answer to your second question. Your first question (what is the relationship between these `TextWriter` objects?) still stands.

Comment: @Bracketworks autoproperties wouldn't affect `ReferenceEquals`, would they? I suppose it depends on where your call to `ReferenceEquals` is actually happening.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well, it's become an academic trial now, however I'm writing some boilerplate output management stuff into HtmlHelpers, and was hoping that the TextWriter available through it's referenced ViewContext would be the same; apparently not.

Comment: Alright, what prevents you from using the `OutputStack` property in your helpers, if that's what works for you?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Because the `HtmlHelper` doesn't have a reference to the current view, only through `ViewContext` is there reference to any `TextWriter` object (*the one causing the aforementioned discrepancy :P*).

Comment: @Bracketworks, you sure 'bout that? Have you tried writing the following expression in your HtmlHelper: `((WebViewPage)html.ViewDataContainer)`. Or more specifically in your case if you wanna be pushing and popping: `var stack = ((WebViewPage)html.ViewDataContainer).OutputStack;`. Tell me if this solves the actual problem you were trying to solve initially so that I can post it as an answer. No need to get academic. Solving real world problems is what is really useful.

Comment: @Bracketworks, this may help you out: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/  Might be less painful than digging through ILSpy.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well I'll be damned.

Comment: @CharlieKilian Thanks; I was going to pull a copy and debug it actually (*by recommendation of a fellow in chat*) provided I didn't get anywhere with this question.

Comment: Just encountered the same issue. ViewContext.Writer and OutputStack.Peek() are in sync at the start of page processing but thereafter they must be manually synchronised. Your "World!" output actually gets compiled to a WebPageBase.WriteLiteral() call, which in turn uses OutputStack.Peek(), so your new ViewContext.Writer is not actually used. I'm now successfully repositioning content in a view (regardless of whether it's literal content in the view, or HtmlHelper output), by manually ensuring that whenever I push/pop to the stack, I also update ViewContext.Writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting my comment as an answer. It might note solve the *academic* part of your question but it might definitely solve the practical part of the question and most importantly the initial problem you were trying to solve.

In your helper you could get the `OutputStack` of the current view:

```
public static void MyHelper(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var stack = ((WebPageBase)html.ViewDataContainer).OutputStack;

    ... you could push and pop here and solve your real world problem
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Darin; I'll play with it and accept your answer momentarily. However, could you elaborate on the relationship between the different `TextWriter` objects involved in my Q? I'm still rather confused.

Comment: Thanks again @Darin; I've accepted as your answer does move my problem along, however I may have to bounty this question in the future to get to the bottom of this :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment above, it appears you need to manually keep OutputStack.Peek() and ViewContext.Writer in sync. The following helper method will do that:

```
    private class WriterScope : IDisposable
    {
        private HtmlHelper _html;
        private TextWriter _previous;

        public WriterScope(HtmlHelper html, TextWriter writer)
        {
            _html = html;
            _previous = _html.ViewContext.Writer;
            _html.ViewContext.Writer = writer;
            ((WebPageBase)_html.ViewDataContainer).OutputStack.Push(writer);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            var stack = ((WebPageBase) _html.ViewDataContainer).OutputStack;
            if (stack.Peek() == _html.ViewContext.Writer)
                _html.ViewContext.Writer = _previous;
            stack.Pop();
            _html = null;
            _previous = null;
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable Scope(this HtmlHelper html, TextWriter writer)
    {
        return new WriterScope(html, writer);
    }
```

In the view it can be used like this:

```
@{
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    using (Html.Scope(sw))
    {
        <p>Line 2</p>
        <p>@Html.Raw("Line 3")</p>
        <p>Line 4</p>
    }
}
<p>Line 1</p>
@Html.Raw(sw.ToString())
```

The page outputs the following as expected:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```